# How to plot a contour with directlabels using two different dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am new to ggplot2 and having trouble adding labels with direct labels on a contour plot.
I want to draw a plot with geom_point and stat_contour.  The point plot and contour plot have different data respectively.  I want add labels on the contour with directlabels.

Using following script, I get a plot without directlabels appropriately, but directlabel returns following error.  error: stat_contour requires the following missing aethtics: x, y, z

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
library(akima)

dat<- NULL
dat$x<- c(-1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
dat$y<- c(-0.5, 0.0, 0.5)
dat$z<- matrix(c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.4),ncol=3)

dat0<-cbind( expand.grid(dat$x,dat$y),c(dat$z)) 
colnames(dat0) <- c("x", "y", "z")
dat0<-data.frame(dat0)

nDivX <- 6
nDivY <- 6
z.cubic <- with(dat, bicubic.grid(x=x,y=y,z=z, xlim=c(min(x),max(x)),ylim=c(min(y),max(y)),dx=(max(x)-min(x))/nDivX,dy=(max(y)-min(y))/nDivY) )
z.cubic<-cbind( expand.grid(z.cubic$x,z.cubic$y),c(z.cubic$z)) 
colnames(z.cubic) <- c("x", "y", "z")
z.cubic<-data.frame(z.cubic)

p0 <- ggplot(NULL)
p1 <- geom_point(data=dat0, aes(x=x,y=y) )
p <- p0 +p1 + stat_contour(data=z.cubic, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z , colour=..level..))

#without directlabels
dev.new()
print(p)

#with directlabels
dev.new()
direct.label(p)
```

Giving two different dataframes may causes the trouble, but I want to give separate data because data for contour in my work is relatively large comparing that for point plot.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not getting any error; I am seeing labels on the contours, and I cannot figure out what you expect to see that is not being seen.

Comment: @BondedDust Strange enough, I am able to reproduce the issue with Win7 x64, R 3.1.1, directlabels_2013.6.15. Judging by upvotes, others also could confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but it seems that the problem is with how `direct.label` treats your first `ggplot(NULL)` call. Most likely it looks there for the required aesthetics, but not able to find them.

Here's how you can fix that:

```
pp0 <- ggplot(dat0, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z)) + geom_point()
pp <- pp0 + stat_contour(data=z.cubic, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z, colour=..level..))
```

and now both `print(pp)` and `direct.label(pp)` work as expected.

#### Update

Browsing the source, I found a way to fix the issue by adding the following line right before the last one in `direct.label.ggplot`: `dlgeom$mapping <- c(dlgeom$mapping, L$mapping)`.

#### Update 2

Toby Hocking (package maintainer) answered my message and, as it turns out, the package has indeed been updated to version `directlabels_2014.6.13` on R-Forge, which is correctly pointed out by @user3357659. In fact, the idea I'm proposing here as a workaround for an outdated version `directlabels_2013.6.15` has been already implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your directlabels to the R-Forge version

```
install.packages("directlabels", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
```